# Python Plotly Error

Tags: python, plotly, mapping

It seems that the example code on the plotly website for choropleth maps is out of date and no longer works.

The error I'm getting is:

```
PlotlyError: Invalid 'figure_or_data' argument. Plotly will not be able to properly parse the resulting JSON. If you want to send this 'figure_or_data' to Plotly anyway (not recommended), you can set 'validate=False' as a plot option.
Here's why you're seeing this error:

The entry at index, '0', is invalid because it does not contain a valid 'type' key-value. This is required for valid 'Data' lists.

Path To Error:
['data'][0]
```

The code that I'm trying to run is shown below. It is copied as-is from the plotly website. Anyone have any ideas as to how I can fix it?

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2011_us_ag_exports.csv')

for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].astype(str)

scl = [[0.0, 'rgb(242,240,247)'],[0.2, 'rgb(218,218,235)'],[0.4, 'rgb(188,189,220)'],\
            [0.6, 'rgb(158,154,200)'],[0.8, 'rgb(117,107,177)'],[1.0, 'rgb(84,39,143)']]

df['text'] = df['state'] + '<br>' +\
    'Beef '+df['beef']+' Dairy '+df['dairy']+'<br>'+\
    'Fruits '+df['total fruits']+' Veggies ' + df['total veggies']+'<br>'+\
    'Wheat '+df['wheat']+' Corn '+df['corn']

data = [ dict(
        type='choropleth',
        colorscale = scl,
        autocolorscale = False,
        locations = df['code'],
        z = df['total exports'].astype(float),
        locationmode = 'USA-states',
        text = df['text'],
        marker = dict(
            line = dict (
                color = 'rgb(255,255,255)',
                width = 2
            )
        ),
        colorbar = dict(
            title = "Millions USD"
        )
    ) ]

layout = dict(
        title = '2011 US Agriculture Exports by State<br>(Hover for breakdown)',
        geo = dict(
            scope='usa',
            projection=dict( type='albers usa' ),
            showlakes = True,
            lakecolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
        ),
    )

fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)

url = py.plot(fig, filename='d3-cloropleth-map')
```

Answer (score 1):

`fig` should be of the `Figure` type. Use the `Choropleth` graph object:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
...
data = [go.Choropleth(        
        colorscale = scl,
        autocolorscale = False,
        locations = df['code'],
        z = df['total exports'].astype(float),
        locationmode = 'USA-states',
        text = df['text'],
        marker = dict(
            line = dict(
                color = 'rgb(255,255,255)',
                width = 2)),
        colorbar = dict(
            title = "Millions USD")
        )]

...
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
...
```

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the code. Seems to have fixed something, but I'm still getting an error: PlotlyDataTypeError: The entry at index, '0', is invalid because it does not contain a valid 'type' key-value. This is required for valid 'Data' lists.

Path To Error:
['data'][0]

Comment: data = [go.Choropleth(
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Choropleth'. Seems that Choropleth isn't an option for go? Thanks for your help on this!

Comment: Strange... It's clearly an option [as shown by the source code](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/master/plotly/graph_objs/graph_objs.py#L937). Make sure plotly is up to date `pip install plotly --upgrade` and then get a python prompt up and check the version `import plotly
plotly.__version__`

Comment: I'm using Conda. The version of plotly is v1.3.2.

Comment: Current version is [`v2.2.3`](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/plotly), update using `conda install -c conda-forge plotly` and make sure you are importing the new module